# UICollectionView resembling iOS App Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make a custom layout for `UICollectionView` that looks somewhat like the iOS App Store. Specific features I am looking to have:

- sections are of fixed height (fitting 1, 2 or some other fixed number of rows of items)
- sections are positioned below another, so the user scrolls vertically to access more sections
- items within a section have horizontal scrolling
- section headers are static and do not move as the user scrolls through the items

Seems fairly simple, but when I look for some tutorials on creating a layout like this, I come up with nothing. Any suggestions on where to start?

This is the App Store layout I'd like to emulate (but with possibly more than 1 row in each section):

[image: CollectionView layout]

Comment: I don't think it's a `UICollectionView`. It's either all `UIScrollViews` or a combination of `UIScrollView` and `UITableView`. You can create this by using a `UITableView` where each cell then contains a `UITableView` that is rotated by 90 degrees... There is a Ray Wenderlich tutorial. I just can't find it atm.

Comment: Here you go... http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2

Comment: I'll try that out. `UICollectionView` just seemed like potentially such a clean solution to this, instead of nesting several different objects.

Comment: Yeah, to get round the rotation of the table you could have a UITableView for the vertical scrolling so a cell for "Paid" and cell for "Free" etc... and then each cell is a UICollectionViewDataSource and have a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView. Slightly less work involed.